# Protractor: Store ElementArrayFinder getTexts in Array and return array from method

Tags: arrays, typescript, protractor

I have a situation in protractor where I want to store ElementArrayFinder getTexts in Array and return array from method. I have written the method so far like this:

```
static getAllTexts(elements: ElementArrayFinder) {
    const data: string[] = [];
    elements.each(function(elem) {
        elem.getText().then(function (text) {
            data.push(text);
        });
    });
    return data;
}
```

Here the method is returning blank array but if I print array content inside promise, it is showing the correct data. Can anyone please help me to rewrite the method so it returns all the array data instead of returning null.

Comment: the methods are asynchronous, you have to find a way to wait for all of them to finish before returning.

Comment: If your NodeJS supports async/await, you can try, https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/async-await.md

Answer (score 2):

```
static async getAllTexts(elements: ElementArrayFinder): Promise<string[]> {
    return await elements.map(async (element: ElementFinder) => {
       await element.getText();
    }
}
```

NOTE: you should [turn off Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md) in your `protractor.conf.ts`:

 `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false`

Comment: thx. I see this error : Type 'Promise<{}[]>' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Promise<{}[]>'.

Comment: Because elements.map return a Pomise array, but you declare the function return a string[], so the actual return value type not matched the declare type.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause return empty array is `return data` is executed sync, but `data.push(text)` is executed async. so when `getAllTexts()` execution completed
`data.push(text)` have not start execute, so you got an empty array.

To fix your code issue, please see below **Option 3**

**Option 1)**  call `getText()` on elements directly

```
static getAllTexts(elements: ElementArrayFinder) {
   // directly return raw text
   return elements.getText();

   // or do some formater
   return elements.getText().then(function(txts){
      return txts.map(function(txt){
          return txt.replace('%', '').trim();
      });
   })
}
```

**Option 2)**  use `map()`

```
static getAllTexts(elements: ElementArrayFinder) {

   return elements.map(function(item){

      // directly return raw text
      return item.getText();

      // or do some formater
      return item.getText().then(function(txt){
         return txt.replace('%', '').trim();
      });
   });
}
```

**Option 3)** user `each()`

```
static getAllTexts(elements: ElementArrayFinder) {
   var txts = [];

   return elements.each(function(item){
      return item.getText().then(function(txt){

        // directly return raw text
        txts.push(txt);

        // or do some formater
        txts.push(txt.replace('%', '').trim());
      });

   }).then(function(){
      return txts;
   });
}
```